# Passing a string to XMLHttprequst

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I'm in a death loop trying to resolve this one. When I pass my api url to XMLHttprequest as text it works. When I pass it as a variable the request sticks waiting for the state change and nothing happens. I am certain the variable being passed is there and it's the correct string. The console output works. I've tried it as both a URL and text. I've formatted it before and after passing. NOTHING works. I've eliminated everything else, it just won't read the variable. I'm assuming this has to to with the inner workings of the request and having access to the url variable? What am I missing?????

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJfxn.png)

Comment: Your "test" variable name isn't using var/let/const so it could be affected by another global somewhere else in your application. Have you already tried setting your new variable to the exact string instead of the value from this.props? Also, it's not clear to me what you mean by "I've tried it as both a URL and text. I've formatted it before and after passing." If you are formatting the string from this.props.url.href, is it not a complete URL already?

Comment: I first tried using "let", then i tried defining globally like "xhr". Neither worked. What i meant about URL and text is I passed the prop as both a URL object and just the url string itself. I tried every way to pull the link out and it did't make a difference, so I am sure it's not syntax in the prop. Yes, I have also tried defining the url string right outside of the API call and it also fails.

Comment: A bit of clarification: declaring a string locally and passing it to the API works. The issue arises when that value is tied back to the props. That's why I thought it was a syntax thing with the props,  but that doesn't seem to be the issue. When I print the prop to console it's always correct. When I pass it to the API call it doesn't work.